# Are minifying and bundling the same operation?

Tags: code, terminology

I have the problem that MediaWiki doesn't support certain new JavaScript syntaxes (possibly >= ES 2015); quoting from MediaWiki support desk:

> MediaWiki performs JavaScript bundle and minification. The library that performs the minification may not support this syntax yet, that's why it's not being applied.

Is minifying and bundling (the aforementioned "bundle") the same operations?

### Update

After reading MrWhite's answer I understand that "bundling" here is what I knew several years already as "aggregation", the common term in the Drupal community.

Comment: It's worth noting that while bundling and minification are different processes, they are often done by the same tool, together in a single pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take it that "bundling" is the combining of several files into fewer (or even a single) files in order to reduce the number of separate HTTP requests the browser needs to make.

Minification is the process of reducing the size of those files.

These are two different operations.

Comment: Oh, I know "bundling" as "aggregation".

Comment: @variableism Whilst "bundling" and "aggregation" have _similar_ meaning, I wouldn't necessarily use "aggregation" in this context. "bundling" is literally packing items together to save space. Whereas "aggregation" is just grouping items together. In a web context, it is more commonly used with things like "news/content aggregation" etc. If Drupal uses "aggregation" for the specific task of combining files into a package then I would have said this is reasonably unique to Drupal.

Comment: MrWhite, thanks, in the context of JavaScript, wouldn't that always be the same thing (unifying all into one big file)?